# Allow only one xaml Datatrigger to be activated at one time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ControlTemplate, which contains the status of a device. In this status  the device program can be displayed, which consists of three steps. The animation index property regulary counts from 1 to 3 up. Also the device could perform three operations, which are independently of the program. However the programm should have a higher priority. Operation1 and Operation2 could not occur at the same time. Operation3 should have the lowest priority. When neither an operation nor the program is active the control remains empty.

Using a datatrigger I change the visibility of the canvases, depending on the status.
I only want to allow one trigger to be raised at the same time. At the moment I need much code to collapse the invisible parts. Also I rely on the order the conditions are checked: From top to bottom in the code. Which is bad style.(which could be avoided by even more code)

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Viewbox Width="30" Height="24" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Canvas Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="30.6667" Height="26.6667">
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceProgramIdle"Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceProgramStepA" Width="30.6667" Height="26.6667" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceProgramStepB" Width="30.6667" Height="26.6667" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceProgramStepC" Width="30.6667" Height="26.6667" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceOperation1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceOperation2" Height="24" Width="30" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceOperation3" Width="30.6667" Height="26.6667" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DeviceViewModel.IsOperation1Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation1" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramIdle" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepA" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepB" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepC" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DeviceViewModel.IsOperation2Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation2" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramIdle" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepA" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepB" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepC" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding DeviceViewModel.IsOperation1Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding DeviceViewModel.IsOperation2Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding DeviceViewModel.IsOperation3Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="false"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation3" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramIdle" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepA" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepB" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepC" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type devic:DeviceProgram}}, Mode=OneWay}" Value="1">
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation1" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation2" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation3" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepA" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type devic:DeviceProgram}}, Mode=OneWay}" Value="2">
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation1" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation2" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation3" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepB" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type devic:DeviceProgram}}, Mode=OneWay}" Value="3">
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation1" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation2" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation3" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepC" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: If everything is `Collapsed` by default, and your conditions are mutually exclusive, you only need to write the `Visible' cases.

Comment: And if you want animations... then use WPF `animation` and `storyboard`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested `@P.Manthe` Set `Visibility="Collapsed"` by default for all Canvases and set only `Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"` for canvas which need to be visible

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Viewbox Width="30" Height="24" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Canvas Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="30.6667" Height="26.6667">
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceProgramIdle"Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceProgramStepA" Width="30.6667" Height="26.6667" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceProgramStepB" Width="30.6667" Height="26.6667" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceProgramStepC" Width="30.6667" Height="26.6667" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceOperation1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceOperation2" Height="24" Width="30" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="deviceOperation3" Width="30.6667" Height="26.6667" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    ...
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DeviceViewModel.IsOperation1Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation1" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DeviceViewModel.IsOperation2Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation2" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding DeviceViewModel.IsOperation1Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding DeviceViewModel.IsOperation2Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding DeviceViewModel.IsOperation3Active, Mode=OneWay}" Value="false"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="deviceOperation3" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type devic:DeviceProgram}}, Mode=OneWay}" Value="1">
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepA" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type devic:DeviceProgram}}, Mode=OneWay}" Value="2">
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepB" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type devic:DeviceProgram}}, Mode=OneWay}" Value="3">
            <Setter TargetName="deviceProgramStepC" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: You need to set `Visibility="Collapsed"` also in style - properties set inline override styles, so all canvases will be collapsed regardless of your datat riggers